# Relational database querying failing

Tags: php, mysql

I am ever so close to resolving the issue I have with taking some data from my tables, basically I have a users tables, a category tables and a join tables which has foreign keys assigned to the user_id from the users table and the cat_id taken from the cats table.

I basically want to show different categories if they have been assigned to you and in my database in the join table I can select a user id and cat id and that has its own id in a row. the trouble i face is getting those categories to show against the users id when logged in?

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
require ('../db_con.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    // BUILD AND DISPLAY THE CATEGORY LIST (RICOH BUILD)
    function build_cat_list()
    {

    global $dbc;

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    $q = sprintf("
        SELECT
           count(*)
        FROM
            cats
        INNER JOIN
            user_cat_join
        ON
            cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
        WHERE
            user_cat_join.user_id = '%s'
        ",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $user)
    );

    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    echo '
    <a href="view_cat.php?cat_id='.$row["cat_id"].'">
        <div class="indexBox"">
            <div class="indexBoxHeader"  style="background-color:'.$row["cat_color"].'"><p>'
                .$row["cat_icon"].'</p>
                </div>
            <div class="indexBoxFooter">
                <p>'.$row["cat_name"].'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>';

    }

}
?>
```

As it stand, it is running through the entire script because what it does it builds a little box with an icon, a background color and a name printed on the box. But at the moment it renders the box but tells me there are some undefined variables which I know what the error means but struggling to overcome it?

```
Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\MAMP\htdocs\functions\functions.inc.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: cat_color in C:\MAMP\htdocs\functions\functions.inc.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: cat_icon in C:\MAMP\htdocs\functions\functions.inc.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: cat_name in C:\MAMP\htdocs\functions\functions.inc.php on line 42
```

And of course the above variables are referring to the bottom part where it actually renders out the box. It will only show me these undefined variables if I use `count(*)` but if I specify them like cat_name, cat_color etc etc I get nothing and no errors?

Comment: Your query is only selecting `count(*)` -> `SELECT count(*) FROM ...`. So where do you expect those column names are to come from?

Comment: Doh... heehhehe Copy/Paste will get you every time

Comment: sidenote: has the session been started?

Comment: Rather than using the `mysqli_real_escape_string` and its brethen, look into using prepared statements.  They are easier to use in the long run.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey yeah my session is being started in my header which is included on the page

Comment: When you specify your column names, you are probably getting an error like `Column 'cat_id' in field list is ambiguous` if you have a column name that is in both tables, unless you specify the table `cats.cat_id`

Comment: @Sean so now I asking for cats.cat_id the error message has gone but no errors or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to select the columns that you actually want to use

```
$q = sprintf("
        SELECT
            cats.cat_id,cat_color,cat_icon, cat_name
        FROM cats
        INNER JOIN user_cat_join
        ON cats.cat_id = user_cat_join.cat_id
        WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = '%s'
        ",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $user) );
```

It would be better to use a prepared statement here but to keep it simple!

Comment: This will cause a `Column 'cat_id' in field list is ambiguous` error.

Comment: Good point, ill amend it. Obviously my brain does not do SQL compilation on the fly

Comment: Now the error has gone I get no errors despite error reporting on, and nothing to suggest it has failed?

Comment: Do you means by that **Yippeee it works** or no errors reported but **still does not work**

Comment: So what is not working. Some debugging is required from your end

Answer (score 0):

Run the query using:

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q)
or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
```

This will give you the report of what error your query is running into and you can adjust the query accordingly

Change the query as RiggsFoly says and check that $user value is the right one.

As per your comments you are passing to the query in your script a value that is different from what you tested in phpmyadmin. Probably $user in your code is:

1. The wrong value to be put in the query;
2. The right value but for it there are no data.

Run the query in phpmyadmin **with the $user value you echo in the code and you will understand what is your case.**

Comment: `mysqli_error()` requires the db link -> `mysqli_error($dbc)`. see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: If you look closely. the query works fine, it is just not selecting any of the columns that they then try and use

Comment: you are right! will edit the answer. It's a bit of time since I last used mysql or mysqli...

Comment: @RiggsFolly but OP also says: "but if I specify them like cat_name, cat_color etc etc I get nothing and no errors?"

Comment: Here is what I get from using the suggested: `Couldn't execute query: Column 'cat_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @phpcoder you have to specify the table name of the table you want the cat_id value to come from. See RiggsFolly for his updated answer

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have amended it to reflect the suggestion but now I get no return

Comment: at this point it is a matter of data. Probably, with the condition you have set the query finds no data. You don't see any error because the query is working fine on a syntax side but you have to check data and join. Maybe you can edit your question to set up a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Just run your query using phpMyAdmin or whatever you use. Does the query actually return any rows?

Comment: Interestingly, I changed it to specify that user in phpymyadmin and it does return the two rows I was expecting. However, there is something obviously a miss with my code because it stlil shows blank?

Comment: @phpcoder and if you echo $user do you get the expected value?

Comment: If I echo out $user it gives me the session number

Comment: Is it what you expected? Is that value what you replaced in your query when you run it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I replaced `WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = '%s'` with `WHERE user_cat_join.user_id = 11` in phpmyadmin and it returned the two rows I was expecting

Comment: No, 11 is the user ID i knew of to test against - I understand my code above makes a reference to user who is logged in and then knows which categories to show?